# How i can lower down JSP memory usage.?

Tags: java, memory-management, profiling

Recently i had a crash analysis meeting and I was made aware that the crash happened due to huge JSP memory usage.

I want to know if there is a way it can be detected in a earlier stage that like "hey ! jsp memory usage is increasing". Or How to detect it , what can we do so it does not increases or remedies to lower it when it increases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your webapp isn't just popular and needs more memory:

A **performance analysis** might help you to determine which functionality of your webapp (jsp file) needs that many resources (memory) and has to be optimized (allocating too many objects instead of reusing them comes to mind).

For a performance analysis:

- VisualVM http://visualvm.java.net/features.html
- concurrent users
  with HtmlUnit http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/ (with JavaScript
  interpretation as well)
- Apache JMeter jmeter.apache.org/